# WhisperAI Transcription returns repeating words in the end of transcript. Does anyone know why?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, openai-whisper

I am running whisper transcription ("base.en") model on an audio file

"https://test-trimpixel.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/meetingbot//tmp/1672172602702-gzn-rcck-som.ogg", keeping temperature=0 as parameter. But it is returning repeating words in the end of transcript.

In this case it is returning:

> Okay. Okay. Okay. Go back. Just go to form. I hope. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Go back. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Go back. Okay. Go back. There was one of those meetings where, you know, we did not get any recordings. So we need to go through those. Can you start from the 1245? Is the meeting at 1245 AM? 1245. 1245 AM. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. Okay. So 52 has not even said video. And 53, you know, 53. What is there to get 53 53. It's not just look at the test. Already the bodies are more. You can play the video. Okay. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Here is code for the reference:

```
model = whisper.load_model("base.en")
outFile = fileName.split('.ogg')[0] + '.wav'
result = model.transcribe(outFile,  temperature=0)
print(result['text'])
```